# GitHub - Using multiple deploy keys on a single server

Tags: bash, git, apache, github, ssh

### Background

I have a system where when I push changes to my Repository, A web hook sends a request to my site which runs a bash script to pull the changes and copy any updated files.

I added a second repository with its own deploy key but after doing so i was getting a permission denied error when trying to pull changes.

### Question

Is there a way to use 2 deploy key's on the same server?

### Environment Details

- Site uses Laravel 5.6, Symfony used to run shell script
- Git 1.7
- Go Daddy web hosting (Basic Linux one)

### Notes

- Script just runs `git pull` command
- Error given is " Permission denied (publickey) "
- SHH is used as a deploy key so only read access, there is one other project also using a deploy key on the same server

Thank you in advance for you help! Any other suggestions are welcome!

#### Edit #1

Edited post to reflect true problem as it was different to what I though (Feel free to revert if this is bad practice), please see answer below for details and solution

Comment: If you use an SSH key you shouldn't need to use a password - that's the idea of public SSH keys.

Comment: What happens if your run your script as that user when you SSH in? `su -c <script> -s /bin/bash username`

Comment: You may enable login for www-data, setup a home folder for this www-data user and drop your ssh-keys ~www-data/.ssh/ and fix folder and file permission. [**sharing ssh-keys is NOT a good idea**]

Comment: @ResetACK That is the setup i had before but with github 2FA enabled it only works if the key has a passphrase

Comment: @Brandon Miller says 'su: command not found'.

Comment: @Robert Ranjan not sure if I can login as this user since it is the web-servers user not an actual account.

Comment: Have you looked at using a deploy key https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Comment: @osowskit Yes that is what I was previously using, however since adding 2FA to my GitHub account the deploy key will not work unless is has a passphrase, I just get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i though was an issue with authentication what actually an issue with the git service not knowing which ssh key to use as i had multiple on the server.

The solution was to use a config file in the .ssh folder and assign alias to specify which ssh key to use for git operations in separate repositories.

Solution is here: [Gist with solution](https://gist.github.com/jamesmcfadden/d379e04e7ae2861414886af189ec59e5)

This gist explains the general idea, it suggests using sub-domains however a comment further down uses alias which seems neater.

I have now resolved the issue and the system is working fine with a read-only, passphrase-less deploy key.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by customizing the GIT_SSH_COMMAND. As ssh .config only gets the host, you have to create aliases to handle different paths. Alternatively, as the git CLI [sends the path of the repo](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e870325/connect.c#L1268) to the GIT_SSH_COMMAND, you can intercept the request in a custom script, added in between git and ssh.

You can create a solution where you extract the path and add in the related identity file, if available on the server.

One approach to do this can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vhermecz/4e2ae9468f2ff7532bf3f8155ac95c74).

Usage:

```
cp deploy_key_file ~/.ssh/git-keys/github-practice
GIT_SSH_COMMAND=custom_keys_git_ssh git clone git@github.com:github/practice.git
```